# SpringMVC 3 Spring Security Creating User Login

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-set-up-and.html) to create a spring mvc user login page.

The tutorial is great but one thing is not clear, on the [second page](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-user-in.html) he talks about the `UserRepository` interface. The interface methods return `User`. What I'm confused about is of the `User` he's referring to is the `User` object part of the spring framework? The reason I ask if because I want to have an email address field which is not there in the `User` object which is part of the Spring security framework.

Also, in his implementation of the `UserLoginService` he has a method:

```
@Override
public User getLoggedUser() {
    User loggedUser = null;
    AuthenticationUserDetails userDetails = getLoggedUserDetails();
    if (userDetails != null) {            
        loggedUser = userRepository.findById(userDetails.getId());
    }
    return loggedUser;
}
```

the trouble is that the `AuthenticationUserDetails` does not have a `getId()` method, which makes me think he intends us to extend Spring's User to create our own Account entity or something.

I want to use Hibernate to create my `Account` and `Role` entities and so far every tutorial I've found seems to be before Spring MVC 3 or just giving bits and pieces.

Can anyone provide clarification on this or refer me to a good tutorial for User Login with Spring Security and SpringMVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` is a Spring Security `UserDetails` object.  If you want to extend the object to add more fields, implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and extend the `UserDetails` object with your own fields.  Then configure Spring Security to use your service, as follows:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I'm using hibernate, so I implement `UserDetails` to create my own `User` object, then I would also have to implement `GrantedAuthorities` to create my own `Role` entity. Is this correct?

Comment: Not exactly.  All you need to do is create a `List` of `GrantedAuthority` objects by using `new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_SOME_ROLE")` and add the `List` to your `User` object.  Example: http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a stab at this (again) later today.